# Okhttp3 in Kotlin, String.mediaType() does not work

Tags: networking, kotlin, header, okhttp, media-type

This is the code that I am trying to do but it doesn't work.

```
 val JSON = String.format("application/json; charset=utf-8").toMediaType()
  (headers as Map<String, String>).toHeaders()
```

I did import: `import okhttp3.MediaType` 
What do I need to do to make it recognise the toMediaType and toHeaders methods?

Comment: Why do you have a call to `String.format`? It seems unnecessary

Comment: I don't in my actual code. But trying to find out why it wouldn't recognise .toMediaType, I tried that to see if it helps. Still a bit knew to kotlin, and well, tried both `val JSON : String` and the other, wasn't aware I need to import the companion, but now I know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The extension functions are in companion objects:

```
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaType
import okhttp3.Headers.Companion.toHeaders
```

Answer (score 14):

Adding the import to my gradle file to force version 4.7.2 solved it

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2"
```